# SetTimer does not change time interval

Tags: windows, winapi, timer, message

I am using SetTimer to put a timer in my game, the timer will be triggered every 1000 ms, after some time, I want to change the time interval of the timer, so I call SetTimer again with the same timerId(according to MSDN, this will replace the old timer with the new time-out), but it seems not work, the timer was not fired.

here is my code, this is a typical game loop.

```
INT WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX winClass ;

    winClass.lpszClassName = L"RotationBySetTimer";
    winClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    winClass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    winClass.lpfnWndProc   = MsgProc;
    winClass.hInstance     = hInstance;
    winClass.hIcon         = NULL ;
    winClass.hIconSm       = NULL ;
    winClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
    winClass.hbrBackground = NULL ;
    winClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
    winClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    winClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;

    RegisterClassEx (&winClass) ;  

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,  
        winClass.lpszClassName,     // window class name
        L"RotationBySetTimer",                  // window caption
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
        32,                         // initial x position
        32,                         // initial y position
        600,                        // initial window width
        600,                        // initial window height
        NULL,                       // parent window handle
        NULL,                       // window menu handle
        hInstance,                  // program instance handle
        NULL) ;                     // creation parameters

    **SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 1000, NULL);**

    // Initialize Direct3D
    if( SUCCEEDED(InitD3D(hWnd)))
    { 
        // Show the window
        ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
        UpdateWindow( hWnd );

        MSG msg ; 
        ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof(msg) );
        PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_NOREMOVE );

        // Get last time
        static DWORD lastTime = timeGetTime();

        while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)  
        {
            if(PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) != 0)
            {
                TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
                DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
            }
            else // Render the game if there is no message to process
            {
                // Get current time
                DWORD currTime  = timeGetTime();

                // Calculate time elapsed
                float timeDelta = (currTime - lastTime) * 0.001f;

                // Render
                Render(hWnd, timeDelta) ;

                // Update last time to current
                lastTime = currTime;
            }
        }
    }

    UnregisterClass(winClass.lpszClassName, hInstance) ;
    return 0;
}
```

and I call SetTimer again in Render function to change the time interval.

```
void Render(HWND hWnd, float timeDelta)
{
    **SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 2000, NULL);**

    if (!g_bActive)
    {
        Sleep(50) ;
    }

    SetupMatrix() ;

    // Clear the back-buffer to a RED color
    g_pd3dDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,0), 1.0f, 0 );

    // Begin the scene
    if( SUCCEEDED( g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene() ) )
    {
        // Draw teapot 
        g_pTeapotMesh->DrawSubset(0) ;

        // End the scene
        g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();
    }

    // Present the back-buffer contents to the display
    g_pd3dDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}
```

The code works well before I call SetTimer again in Render function, but stop working after adding this line, why?

Comment: In order for you to receive `WM_TIMER` messages, your code has to be pumping the message loop. If you're stuck in a computationally-intensive render that does not stop periodically to pump the message loop, you will not receive `WM_TIMER` messages regardless of the timer's interval. If you comment out the second call to `SetTimer`, do you actually receive `WM_TIMER` messages every 1000 ms?

Comment: Yes, it works when I comment out the second call to SetTimer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you coded it, you are calling SetTimer() at a high rate over and over again.  Constantly resetting the timer and thus never allowing enough time to pass for the WM_TIMER message to ever get posted.

Clearly you'll need to find a better trigger to update the timer.  Maybe by only calling SetTimer when the interval value actually needs to change.  It isn't that clear how to best do this from the posted code since it doesn't have an obvious trigger condition.

Comment: That's not the case, I change the time interval to 500ms, it still not work.

Comment: The code I post is just an example, the real logic is when the user got a score over 20, the game speed will change, so the timer was triggered when the score reach 20.

Comment: I think I got you, the render function was called every frame, and the timer was reset every frame, if the frame rate bigger than the time interval, it will never fired.

Comment: I update my code with a static variable, it works now, thank you very much!
`if( gameScore >= 1 )
{
 static bool isUpdate = false;
 if(!isUpdate)
 {
  SetTimer(this->hWnd, 123, 500, NULL);
  isUpdate = true;
 }
}
`